# Now we get the EEA family permit London now not in a European countries

Tags: united-kingdom, visa, immigration, brexit

Hi somebody tell now uk is not in a European Union anymore and I have a ticket of 30th June from Romania to London with my wife and son actually I am Indian my wife from Romania we going from the EU rules and apply the EEA FAMILY PERMIT now Wats the new rule to get the EEA FAMILY PERMIT.

Answer (score 2):

The UK is still in the European Union, and will continue being so for at least the next 2 years.

No rules have changed today.